# VS2012 Metro App SplashScreen - failing WACK test

Tags: image, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Having completed my Windows 8 Metro App, I'm trying to push it through a "Windows Application Certification Kit" test.  It failed because my SplashScreen logo was too big.  I get the following message:

```
App resources validation
Error Found: The app resources validation test detected the following errors: 
 - Image reference "Assets\SplashScreen.png": The image "c:\MyProject\bin\Release\AppX\Assets\SplashScreen.png" failed the size restrictions of 620 X 300.
```

However, I have reduced this size to be much smaller than this now (225 x 300), but am still getting the error.  Also, when I run the app, the splash screen appears the same size (but with a much lower resolution).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make the program recognise the size is decreased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splashscreen should be **exactly** 620 x 300 pixels. Open the package.appmanifest file and you'll see a red error sign on the splash screen image name. You can use a transparent background to make up for the extra margins that you have to include to reach the correct size.